# how to retrive data from the table that have multiple(composite) primary key. In Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, composite-key

I have one table which has composite primary key(2 columns) I need to retrieve data (or particular record) through hibernate (HQL).

Mapping of composite key in `POJOs` is already done. but could not get any help on retrieving the data or an object from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyEntityPK pk = new MyEntityPK(part1, part2);
MyEntity result = session.get(pk);
```

If you want help over a HQL query, show us the entity and its mapping, and tell us what the HQL query should do. But a HQL query is no different for an entity with a composite key than it is for an entity with a non-composite key.